# Proving an affine transformation preserves distance.

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

In a given affine coordinates, an affine transformation is given by:

\begin{cases} x'=3x+y \\ y'=-4x-y \end{cases}

How can I see if it preserves distance? Is it correct to see that the distance between 2 points $(1,0),(0,1)$ is $\sqrt{2}$ and after applying this affine transfromation these two points will become $(3,-4)$ and $(1,-1)$ and the distance between them is $\neq{\sqrt{2}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that would disprove that it is distance preserving.

Remark:

- To prove that distance is not preserved, a counter example suffices.
- To prove that distance is preserved, a general proof is required.